# Globbing file pattern

Tags: gruntjs

I am new to the Grunt Task Runer. I'm trying to do some file matching in one of my configurations. With this file matching, I need ignore all of my test files, except for one. The one test file that I need to keep is named 'basic.test.js' In an attempt to do this, I currently have the following configuration:

```
files: [
  'src/**/*.js',
  '!src/**/*.test.js',
  'src/root/basic.test.js'
]
```

At this time, I am still getting ALL of my tests. This means that my tests in the other test files are still being seen. I'm trying to confirm if I'm doing my globbing pattern correctly. Does my globbing pattern look correct for my scenario?

Thank you!

Comment: strange, that looks correct to me... do see any relevant info when using the `--verbose` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want one test then there is no need to match and then unmatch all the others. Just include the one test:

```
files: [
  'src/root/basic.test.js'
]
```

Comment: If I do that, my app files won't be loaded. Only the test file would. The test AND the .js to test need to be loaded.